# A search for url:* highlights almost every word - which sucks for spam discovery

Tags: bug, search

Spurred by the [crusade against r0uter-switch.com spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/208998/152515), I decided to make a cursory search for possible router spam. Most of the posts contained no links though, so I noticed we have an advanced search for URLs.

I ran [a search for `url:* router`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A*+router), ideally to show all posts that mention 'router' and contain a URL. It turns out that almost every word in each search result is bolded (probably because of that all-encompassing wildcard):

> [image]

If I [search for `url:".com" router`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3a%22.com%22%20router) I'll get all the sites with a **.com** url, and which mention 'router'. In this search, the only things that get bolded are the word 'router' and the domain portion of the URL. Great!

Could we fix the search for `url:*` to only make URLs bold, since that search term itself would be very useful for searching for possible spam suspects?

Comment: Searching for `url:"." router` [seems to work](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22.%22+router), sort of. The highlighting isn't perfect (it seems to highlight anything with a period in the middle of a word, like filenames with a suffix), but it's better than in your screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `url:*` is the obvious way to search for all the links (so ideally highlighting would work with it), you can also use [`url://`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%2F%2F%20router) which returns the same results with no weird highlighting:

> [image]